# How do I access the Vue object within a Vuex module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, module, libraries, vuex

In Vue components, I can easily use imported libraries, such as `vue-router`. I can access the route parameter I need with `this.$route.params.myVar`. However, if I try to do the same within a Vuex module, I get the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'myVar' of undefined`. How can I extend the Vue object I defined in my `main.js` to my modules?

Here's my `main.js`:

```
import router from './router'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import myModule from './my.module';

Vue.use(Vuex)

// Register VueX modules
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    myModule
  }
})

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
  store
}).$mount('#app')
```

And `my.module.js`:

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    ...
  },
  mutations: {
    ...
  },
  actions: {
    someAction() {
      console.log(this.$route.params.myVar)
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously, `this` isn't defined. I tried instantiating a new Vue object at the top of my module like so:

```
var vm = new Vue()
```

And changing `this` to `vm`, but I get a similar `Cannot read property 'myVar' of undefined` error. I also tried re-instantiating the `route` class at the the module:

```
import route from 'vue-router'
```

And changing my failing code to `route.params.myVar`, but I still get the `Cannot read property 'myVar' of undefined` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, you have two options.

- Pass param.myvar from outside inside vuex action
- Import router into vuex module and use it

For the second option make sure to import your router declaration and not the library. For example.

```
import router from '@/router'

router.currentRoute.params.myVar
```

Comment: The second option was the solution I was looking for. Thanks!